# Filtering null values in Scala

Tags: scala, hive

I have a hive table that has null and empty values in some columns. Null values representation in my table is `\N`.
I am trying to select rows that column a is not null in Scala.
I have tried using

a. `if (a.equals("\\N"))`

b. `if (!Option(a).getOrElse("").isEmpty)`

c. using `length(trim(a))`

None of these options worked for my code either the filter does not work or all rows get excluded.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: A bit more code may be helpful here. When I create `val a = "\\N"`, and test with your option (a) I get `Boolean = true`, which suggests that this should work. More about either your table, or your filtering (ideally both) would help.

Comment: How are you accessing hive through scala?

Comment: What type is inferred for `a` from the row select? Also which error pops up for instance from filtering?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform, Hive's \N is a string, that is "\N", however in Java and hence in Scala that's represented as "\N" which can be matched using {scala.Predef.String = java.lang.String}.matches("\\N") as in the following test:

```
val s = "\\N"
println(s.matches("\\\\N")) // prints true
```

If that does not work for you please provide information about how you are accessing the hive table and the hive version so I can attempt to replicate an error.